# cant run web app on server - runs fine in Debug - permissions problem?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Trying to get a web app to work. Works fine when debugging (in release and Debug mode) but when I publish to a webserver I hit an error when trying to access a local file..

```
"
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
"

"Stack Trace: 


[IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7717304
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +1162
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) +65
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) +87
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path) +30
   ASP_FSR.SmokeBooks.GetSmokeBookList(String configlocation) in C:\ASP_TEST\ASP_FSR\ASP_FSR\SmokeBooks.cs:39
   ASP_FSR.Foundry_Data.getData(String report, String smokeconfig) in C:\ASP_TEST\ASP_FSR\ASP_FSR\Foundry_Data.cs:36
   ASP_FSR.Check.RunCheck() in C:\ASP_TEST\ASP_FSR\ASP_FSR\Check.cs:49
   ASP_FSR._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ASP_TEST\ASP_FSR\ASP_FSR\Default.aspx.cs:65
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
"
```

I have added the user ASP.NET Machine Account (\ASPNET) to the directory where the files are (which is the same as the app)

Answer (score 3):

When you run a webapp in IIS, it is the user that the AppPool runs under that matters.

This varies, so check out the settings IN IIS, and assign permissions for this account instead to the relevant folders.

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/iis-app-pool-identity.html

Comment: thanks, stupid question, how do I find the user the AppPool runs under?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this is a permission issue. If you are certain the ASP.NET account is configure correctly then are you doing any identity impersonation in web.config i.e. `<identity impersonate="true" userName=...` and if so is this account configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your application is trying to access file(s) in the failure. Are you sure you gave the app write/read permission for the file in IIS?

Comment: That may be the answer. I have simply added the ASPNET user access to the folder where all files are located.. So I need to give the app access also?

Answer (score 0):

Late response but was back looking at this site and though I should update for anyone with similar issues.

Yes this was a permissions issue. As mentioned by Barry I needed to impersonate the logon for the server account to access temp dir's etc.